# Two Flet Apps integration with Main Flet App Python

Tags: python, flutter, desktop-application, flet

I have two Flet Apps that are independent. I have another Main flet App with Two buttons, is ot possible to have integration in such a way that first button should open the first FletApp, second button should open second Flet App when clicking the button.

HERE is overall flow diagram, yellow and green color are the buttons in the Main App which is main entry point.
[image]

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. In my case it's not separate apps but one app with many windows. My app is a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Flet has a very easy-to-use navigation and routing system.

See docs for more on this subject [here](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/navigation-and-routing).

Comment: I have used view routing, where i have traversed different views, Is any other way?